# Woocommerce remove "Description" tab and text, but keep content inside

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I wanted to remove "Description" tab and word "Description" from my product page, but keep description content. I've done it (like I wanted). But now the top of the page is "frozen". It is not possible to click on photos, click on the "add to cart" button, and switch the currency. Link to the page: https://www.c60powder.com/product/c60/

What is the problem? What did I do wrong?

I've used that code in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_woocommerce_product_tabs', 98 );

function remove_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['description'] );
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
    return $tabs;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_product_description_tab' );

add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', '__return_empty_string');
```

P.S. It works OK on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.woocommerce-tabs.wc-tabs-wrapper {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0% !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.